# emphatic pronoun punctuation

Tags: punctuation

I'm curious as to why an emphatic pronoun isn't set off by commas. For example, "I, myself, completed the puzzle."

Everything about this seems like "myself" should be set off by commas, but the style is not to use them.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Please provide some actual examples of this.

Comment: @GEdgar It would be rather difficult to give examples of "I, myself, did something" when the OP says is not used.

Comment: "*I, myself, completed the puzzle*." (I would replace the commas with dashes) = I, i.e. the person you are looking at, completed the puzzle." Myself is an emphatic and [probably] in **non-defining** apposition to “I”. “Myself” is added to signal that the listener might not believe you. --  "*I myself completed the puzzle*." = I have already personally completed this puzzle". This is usually followed by some personal comment on the puzzle. As there is no need to define “I”, “myself” is purely emphatic but it is used in **defining** apposition to “I”, and hence sounds pompous or self-important.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.